# How to minify a single css file with webpack?

Tags: css, webpack

While webpack seems to support a wide variety of detailed configuration options, I only want to accomplish the simple task of taking a single css source file located at `project/frontend/static/css/style.css` and outputting a minified version of that css file to `project/frontend/static/css/style.min.css`. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation of webpack that discusses this, as I am *not* importing my CSS from JS, just linking it in the HTML `head` the old fashioned way, so all I want to output is a plain CSS file, just minified.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do without having a JS entry file to give to webpack. You could use this command line tool maybe? https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-minify

Answer (score 2):

With webpack you may like to use `mini-css-extract-plugin`

```
npm install --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin
```

This plugin extracts CSS into separate files. It creates a CSS file per JS file which contains CSS. It supports On-Demand-Loading of CSS and SourceMaps.

It builds on top of a new webpack v4 feature (module types) and requires webpack 4 to work.

Please look at the documentation for more info 
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/

Comment: Does this work without importing CSS into a JS file(which what he asked)?.